# How to set the variables of LSTMCell as input instead of letting it create it in Tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, lstm

When I create a tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell, it creates its **kernel** and **bias** trainable variables during initialisation.

How the code looks now:

```
cell_fw = tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell(hidden_size_char,
                        state_is_tuple=True)
```

What I want it to look:

```
kernel = tf.get_variable(...)
bias = tf.get_variable(...)
cell_fw = tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell(kernel, bias, hidden_size,
                        state_is_tuple=True)
```

What I want to do is to create those variables myself, and give it to the LSTMCell class when instantiating it as input to its init.

Is there an easy way to do this? I looked at the [class source code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.3/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn_cell_impl.py) but it seems that it is within a complex hierarchy of classes.

Answer (score 2):

I subclassed the LSTMCell class, and changed its *init* and *build*
methods so that they accept given variables. If variables are given in init
within build, we wouldn't use *get_variable* anymore, and would use the given kernel and bias variables.

There might be cleaner ways to do it though.

```
_BIAS_VARIABLE_NAME = "bias"
_WEIGHTS_VARIABLE_NAME = "kernel"

class MyLSTMCell(tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell):
    def __init__(self, num_units,
                 use_peepholes=False, cell_clip=None,
                 initializer=None, num_proj=None, proj_clip=None,
                 num_unit_shards=None, num_proj_shards=None,
                 forget_bias=1.0, state_is_tuple=True,
                 activation=None, reuse=None, name=None, var_given=False, kernel=None, bias=None):

        super(MyLSTMCell, self).__init__(num_units,
                 use_peepholes=use_peepholes, cell_clip=cell_clip,
                 initializer=initializer, num_proj=num_proj, proj_clip=proj_clip,
                 num_unit_shards=num_unit_shards, num_proj_shards=num_proj_shards,
                 forget_bias=forget_bias, state_is_tuple=state_is_tuple,
                 activation=activation, reuse=reuse, name=name)

        self.var_given = var_given
        if self.var_given:
            self._kernel = kernel
            self._bias = bias


    def build(self, inputs_shape):
        if inputs_shape[1].value is None:
            raise ValueError("Expected inputs.shape[-1] to be known, saw shape: %s"
                             % inputs_shape)

        input_depth = inputs_shape[1].value
        h_depth = self._num_units if self._num_proj is None else self._num_proj
        maybe_partitioner = (
            partitioned_variables.fixed_size_partitioner(self._num_unit_shards)
            if self._num_unit_shards is not None
            else None)
        if self.var_given:
            # self._kernel and self._bais are already added in init
            pass
        else:
            self._kernel = self.add_variable(
                _WEIGHTS_VARIABLE_NAME,
                shape=[input_depth + h_depth, 4 * self._num_units],
                initializer=self._initializer,
                partitioner=maybe_partitioner)
            self._bias = self.add_variable(
                _BIAS_VARIABLE_NAME,
                shape=[4 * self._num_units],
                initializer=init_ops.zeros_initializer(dtype=self.dtype))
        if self._use_peepholes:
            self._w_f_diag = self.add_variable("w_f_diag", shape=[self._num_units],
                                               initializer=self._initializer)
            self._w_i_diag = self.add_variable("w_i_diag", shape=[self._num_units],
                                               initializer=self._initializer)
            self._w_o_diag = self.add_variable("w_o_diag", shape=[self._num_units],
                                               initializer=self._initializer)

        if self._num_proj is not None:
            maybe_proj_partitioner = (
                partitioned_variables.fixed_size_partitioner(self._num_proj_shards)
                if self._num_proj_shards is not None
                else None)
            self._proj_kernel = self.add_variable(
                "projection/%s" % _WEIGHTS_VARIABLE_NAME,
                shape=[self._num_units, self._num_proj],
                initializer=self._initializer,
                partitioner=maybe_proj_partitioner)

        self.built = True
```

So the code will be like this:

```
kernel = get_variable(...)
bias = get_variable(...)
lstm_fw = MyLSTMCell(....., var_given=True, kernel=kernel, bias=bias)
```

Comment: Thank you! I was getting `name 'init_ops' is not defined` error. So inside of my `MyLSTMCell` I added `from tensorflow.python.ops import init_ops`.